# Google App Script - How to get a usage report of Group Mail

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to generate a usage report from my domain on all my group emails like `num_emails_received` in the last 3 months. But it seems Google only support to generate a usage report all my users with `AdminReports.UserUsageReport`.

Please help me with some ideal. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the guide on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post to show what you have tried and what issues you have encountered.

Comment: Do u read my question? `I am trying to generate a usage report from my domain on all my group emails like num_emails_received in the last 3 months.` --> this is my issue. I have read the google documentation but not found any API to generate a usage report on all my Group.

Answer (score 0):

### You can pass `gmail:num_emails_sent` as a parameter inside the Optional query parameters of your [UserUsageReport: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22ziganotschka1%40egs-sbt015.eu%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222019-08-05%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%22gmail%3Anum_emails_sent%22%7D) request.

The syntax for this request in Apps Script is

```
AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get(userKey, date, {parameters:'gmail:num_emails_sent'})
```

Please refer to the [Admin SDK Reports Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports#generate_user_usage_report) for further documentation about implementation of the REPORTS API in Apps Script including sample code.